# How to use annotation processors like lombok while compiling an annotation processor

Tags: java, maven, annotation-processing

How do I make maven use lombok before it compiles my annotation processor? I am currently going crazy over the infinite amounts of options I have for maven, which all boil down to my Test-Class not using my annotation processor.

My Project has an annotation processor sub-project and a test-sub-project, which uses the annotation processor.

The Pom of my AP currently looks like that (only the build part):

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!--<compilerArgs>-proc:none</compilerArgs>-->
                    <annotationProcessors>
                        <annotationProcessor>lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor</annotationProcessor>
                        <annotationProcessor>lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$ClaimingProcessor</annotationProcessor>
                    </annotationProcessors>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok-version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Nothing really works here. When I trigger a full rebuild, I get the message
`package de.derteufelqwe.AutoPlugin does not exist` which is the class that should have been generated.

When I reducy my pom to this

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>-proc:none</compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

all files are properly generated and everything seems to work fine.
But when I try to export my project using mavens 'package' method, I get the error
`java: constructor Cache in class de.derteufelqwe.AutoPluginProcessor.cache.Cache cannot be applied to given types` on the line `new Cache()`. The `Cache` class gets it's constructor from lombok, therefore I suspect that lombok didn't do it's lombok things before maven tried to compile it.

Tl;Dr: How do I make the compiler use lombok before compiling in my IDE and in maven.